# Blender 2.80 does not preview in viewport/render textures when in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, 3d-view

Halo, I upgraded to 2.80 and I have problem seeing the textures in rendered mode when in Cycles. All works fine in Eevee.Same happens when i try to render the image.
All good in Eevee but outputs grey screen when in Cycles.Same happens in CPU/GPU render. I have the latest build installed. It only happens in this Collection/Layer.
In other Collections it all works fine. I have no idea if Im doing anything wrong, or it this could be some Beta bug? Would anybody know, thanks you for any help.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0ND0B7ZCyc&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I had this problem with earlier releases of the Beta. are you using the latest version? They release new builds of the beta daily. It's entirely possible the bug is fixed in a release a day or a week later, as it was for me

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply. Yes,im on the latest build from 12.6.  I am downloading always the latest version hoping it would fix but nothing. It strange it only afects one Collection. So yours got fixed just by installing a new version?

Comment: Yeah, a month ago I was on here saying my models were getting weird artifacts in the realtime render view and then finally it was just the artifacts. But maybe 2 weeks later I downloaded another release where the same file could be viewed bug-free in that mode (I did send the Unity devs an official bug report before then, though)

Comment: ok, so I guess I'm not doing anything wrong, it just might be a bug. Will wait out till the oficial release then, lets see if it works.Thank you!